# Como cadastrar usuários em uma página PHP e salvar no AD do Windows?

Tags: php, windows, servidor, ad

Criei um formulário de cadastro de usuários em PHP e quero salvar no Active Directory, como posso fazer essa integração? obrigado.

Comment: Não entendo muito de coisas como LDAP, mas creio que isto possa ser um começo http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php e http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-add.php, talvez ajude a formular uma resposta a partir disto.